# i am trying to create a new project in django in python 3.4 and got the error below

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, django-1.8

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SAGAR\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 179, in fetch_command
    app_name = commands[subcommand]
KeyError: 'startprojecttest_project'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "C:\Users\SAGAR\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\SAGAR\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\SAGAR\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 182, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\SAGAR\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\SAGAR\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I am new at Django just now I installed Django and I am try to create a new_project using command (`(venv) C:\Users\SAGAR\Desktop\venv>python .\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject test_project`) but I got the error like that and I also set the environment variable like --

```
C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\python.exe;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin;
```

Comment: did you do what the traceback is telling you to do?

Comment: no , actually i dont understand what traceback is telling

Comment: Thanks , i forgot the space between startproject and test_project..

Comment: Maybe See if, in the settings, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is properly defined. or try calling settings.configure() at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 0):

verify if you have added the path variable properly and try with the command

```
    django-admin startproject <project_name>
```

instead of

```
   django-admin.py startproject <project_name>
```